# Why isn't my text being added to my label?

Tags: json, swift, uilabel, swift4

Revised post: So the code posted below is my stuct

```
 struct AnimeJsonStuff: Decodable {
    let data: [AnimeDataArray]
}

struct AnimeLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
    }
}
struct AnimeAttributes: Codable {
    var createdAt   : String?
    var slug : String?
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case createdAt     = "createdAt"
        case slug = "slug"
    }
}
struct AnimeRelationships: Codable {
    var links   : AnimeRelationshipsLinks?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case links     = "links"
    }
}

struct AnimeRelationshipsLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?
    var related   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
        case related     = "related"
    }
}

struct AnimeDataArray: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let type: String?
    let links: AnimeLinks?
    let attributes: AnimeAttributes?
    let relationships: [String: AnimeRelationships]?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case type = "type"
        case links = "links"
        case attributes = "attributes"
        case relationships = "relationships"
    }
}
```

This code is my function for parsing data:

```
    func jsonDecoding() {

    let jsonUrlString = "https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let animeJsonStuff =  try JSONDecoder().decode(AnimeJsonStuff.self, from: data)
            for anime in animeJsonStuff.data {
                //   print(anime.id)
                //    print(anime.type)
                //   print(anime.links?.selfStr)
                let animeName = anime.attributes?.slug
                print(animeName)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.nameLabel.text = animeName
                }

                for (key, value) in anime.relationships! {
                    //   print(key)
                    //   print(value.links?.selfStr)
                    //    print(value.links?.related)
                }
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

This is what the console prints out:

```
Optional("cowboy-bebop")
Optional("cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira")
Optional("trigun")
Optional("witch-hunter-robin")
Optional("beet-the-vandel-buster")
Optional("eyeshield-21")
Optional("honey-and-clover")
Optional("hungry-heart-wild-striker")
Optional("initial-d-fourth-stage")
Optional("monster")
Optional("cowboy-bebop")
Optional("cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira")
Optional("trigun")
Optional("witch-hunter-robin")
Optional("beet-the-vandel-buster")
Optional("eyeshield-21")
Optional("honey-and-clover")
Optional("hungry-heart-wild-striker")
Optional("initial-d-fourth-stage")
Optional("monster")
Optional("cowboy-bebop")
Optional("cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira")
Optional("trigun")
Optional("witch-hunter-robin")
Optional("beet-the-vandel-buster")
Optional("eyeshield-21")
Optional("honey-and-clover")
Optional("hungry-heart-wild-striker")
Optional("initial-d-fourth-stage")
Optional("monster")
```

It now displays the text but it only displays the last optional called monster and not all the other ones when I have three cells. It only displays monster in each cell. 
It should be

1st cell: Cowboy-bebpop
2nd cell: cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira
3rd cell: trigun
and etc

Comment: What's the code calling `didSet` of `post`? `nameLabel` has not frame? No `superview`?

Comment: Where you are adding nameLabel to view? And set frame to nameLabel.

Comment: Hello I edited my post! I got the label to print but its only printing the last one. I added more code as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. I can't see where do you set `post` variable.
2. Where you put `nambeLabel` into Controller's view hierarchy?
3. And maybe you should set `nameLabel.text` in main thread:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.nameLabel.attributedText = attributedText
   }
   ```

Comment: Hello I edited my post! I got the label to print but its only printing the last one. I added more code as well.

Comment: @Dengekiko you have to use `UITableView`: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html